# c# math square root. finding side of an area

Tags: c#

last question of my homework. please help. 
i am so confused i dont even know where to start.
if you could put some comments for me to understand that will be great.

Develop a menu-driven program that inputs a number X and, at the user’s option, finds the area of a square with side `x [Area = x2]`, the area of a circle with radius `X [Area = 3.14 * x2]`, or the area of an equilateral triangle with side `x [Area = Sqrt(3) / 4 * X2]`. Use a case structure to handle the user’s menu  choice.  Use the Sqrt method in the C# Math library. Display an error message if an invalid menu option is selected

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: sorry. you are in wrong place.

Comment: If its homework, you should start by trying by your own first. Create the menu first and work from there. If you encounter any errors doing them, we can help you. We won't just write a program and give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Develop a menu-driven program that inputs a number X and, at the user’s option, 
//finds the area of a square with side x [Area = x2], the area of a circle with radius X [Area = 3.14 * x2],
//or the area of an equilateral triangle with side x [Area = Sqrt(3) / 4 * X2]. 
//Use a case structure to handle the user’s menu choice. Use the Sqrt method in the C# Math library.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 0;
            double b = 0;

            Console.Write("Enter 1 for Area of square :\nEnter 2 For Area of Circle :\nEnter 3 for Equilateral Triangle :\n\n");
            aa:
            a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (a)
            {
                case 1: 
                    Console.Write("\n\nEnter the Value of Side x : ");
                    b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    double area = b * b;
                    Console.Write("\n\nThe area of square is {0}",area);
                    break;

                case 2:
                     Console.Write("\n\nEnter the Value of Side x : ");
                    b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    double circle = (3.14) * (Math.Pow(b, 2));
                    Console.Write("\n\nThe Area of Circle is {0}",circle);
                    break;

                case 3:
                     Console.Write("\n\nEnter the Value of Side x : ");
                    b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    double triangle = ((Math.Sqrt(3)) / 4) * (Math.Pow(b, 2));
                    Console.Write("\n\nThe Area of Triangle is {0}",triangle);
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.Write("\n\nEnter Correct Number : ");
                    goto aa;                    
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```